# If $v$ doubles, what will the value of $h$ be?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation

**So, I came across this problem:**

A skier goes from position A to position B, and then in B, rises again.
[image]

What must be the height ($h$) for the skier to reach B with double the velocity.
I can't seem to be able to figure this out.

(Ignore non-conservative forces)

Here's what I tried:
I tried to find the relationship between $h$ and $v_B$.

($h=h_A$)

So:
$$E_{m_{A}} = E_{m_{B}}\iff mgh=\frac{1}{2}mv_B^2\iff gh=\frac{1}{2}v_B^2\iff gh=\frac{v_B^2}{2}\iff h=\frac{v_B^2}{2g}$$

And also $v$:$$v^2=2gh\iff v=\sqrt{2gh}\iff 2v=2\sqrt{2gh}$$

In the solutions of the problem it says that if $v$ doubles, $h$ quadruples, but what I got is that $2v=2\sqrt{2gh}$, and this would mean that $2v=2\sqrt{2g}\times\sqrt{h}$, so $2v=\sqrt{4\times 2g}\times \sqrt{h}=\sqrt{8g}\times \sqrt{h}$.

But how does this become $2v=4h$?

I've tried everything I could to understant this.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Double what velocity?

Comment: *But how does this become $2v=4h$?* $2v=4h$ is dimensionally inconsistent and thus does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

$$2v = \sqrt{2g(4h)}$$
This says that height must quadruple for velocity to double.

If this isn't clear, just solve for $h$:
$$h = \frac{v^2}{2g}.$$
If you double $v$, then $v^2$ and $h$ quadruple. In other words, the height $h'$ you need to double the velocity is
$$h' = \frac{(2v)^2}{2g}=4\frac{v^2}{2g}=4h.$$

Comment: "This says that height must quadruple for velocity to double."

Well the problem didn't say that, it said to find the value of $h$ if $v$ doubled.

But thanks

Comment: @Manuel Isn't the last equation what you are looking for?